# Zero derivative calculation during optimization (no impact to objective)

Tags: optimization, openmdao

I am writing an optimization code for a finite-difference radiation solver model. I started to use "src_indices" for connecting parameters rather promoting all the variables. But when I changed the connection, optimization does not calculate derivatives, gives "no impact to objective" error, and successfully terminates optimization after first iteration. Could not find any clue for finding the error in the logs (Bug may be in a completely different reason).

Is there any suggestion where I can start?

I uploaded the code to GitHub https://github.com/TufanAkba/opt_question

Comment: My problem was defining partials. In each component, specifically defined partials as fd or exact (if derivatives are declared in declared_partials). Then optimization runs successfully. It is something I do not understand clearly because for solving the problem everything works properly but in optimization it does not work. I think framework should give a warning.

Comment: You got a warning about 0 total derivatives, which let you know you had a problem. The N2 helped you find a missing connection. Then you had bad partial derivatives. OpenMDAO provides both `check_partials` and `check_totals` methods to verify derivatives. You should run at least `check_partials` before trying any optimizations that need derivatives. 

There is a full section of the docs on derivative verification: http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.15.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/main.html#verifying-partial-derivatives-are-correct

Comment: @JustinGray, thanks for your comment and for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind when you mention "design variables have no impact on objective" is that there may be a missing connection. Since this behavior only started after you changed the connection style, I think this is even more likely.

There are a couple of tools you can use to diagnose this. The first is the n2 viewer, which you can launch by typing the following at your command prompt:

```
openmdao n2 receiver_opt.py
```

This will launch a browser window that contains a graphical model viewer which is described in detail [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/model_visualization/n2_details/n2_details.html). You can use this to explore the structure of your model. To find unconnected inputs in your model, look for any input blocks that are colored `orange`. These are technically connected to a hidden `IndepVarComp` called `_auto_ivc`, and will include design variables, which are set by the optimizer. You will want to look for any that should be connected to other component outputs.

OpenMDAO also has a connection viewer that just shows connections.

```
openmdao view_connections receiver_opt.py
```

You can use this tool to just focus on the connections. It is described [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/model_visualization/view_connections.html). If you choose to use this, just filter to see any connection to `_auto_ivc` in the source output string to see the unconnected inputs.

If you reach this point, and are satisfied that all the connections are correct, then there are a couple of other possibilities:

1. Are all of your src_indices correct? Maybe some of them are an empty set, or maybe some create a "degenerate" case. For example, if you have a set of cascading components that each multiply an incoming vector by a diagonal matrix, and if your indices are [0] in one connection, and [4] in another connection, then you've effectively severed the entire model. None of our visualization tools can pick that up, and you will need to inspect the indices manually.
2. It could also be a derivative problem, though what you describe sounds like connections. In that case, I recommend using [check_partials](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/basic_check_partials.html) to look for any missing or incorrect derivatives.
3. Are you computing any derivatives using complex step? It is possible that you are losing the complex part of the calculation through a complex-unsafe operation.  Checking your derivatives against 'fd' can help to find these.

Comment: n2 & view_conn are done, one connection was missing and connected. Problem continues.
I checked src_indices at runtime by printing out (could not find another way), they look correct.
I comment out all compute_partial methods then rerun, problem still continues.
I am using fd for not dealing with complex overloaded operations, still derivatives are zero. I realized derivative calculation takes approx. 1 second for correctly working optimization code. But now, it is less than 5ms.